# how to check database of my running app in android studio where its stored?

Tags: android-studio

when I run my project in emulated device I'm able to find where its database and root is (device monitor :- data -> data-> package name -> database) and I made some changes in database manually such as add table modify table using sqlite browser and its reflecting good in emulated device while running app but same thing I want when I run in real device but its being difficult to find where this created database exist in real device. I think it should be in internal memory but android device monitor is not displaying the internal memory and root should be (internal m/m : android -> data -> package name -> database) something like this. because I can see all package of all installed apps in external memory but I couldn't find this root in internal memory. please let me know how can I find database?

Comment: you cant get database from real device if it is not rooted.

Comment: please could you give me short info how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

To access your database you need to have a rooted device and an app called root browser. this app will allow you to access all the file just like you access them using device monitor. without rooting, you can not access your database.